# Exponential Growth/Decay when a substance completely decays

Tags: calculus

Is it possible to calculate when a substance completely decays using the formula:

dP/dt = kP(t)

For example; If you know the half-life of a substance; is it possible to calculate the time at which it completely decays? Or you can't since it'd approach -∞ or ∞ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model of continuous exponential decay never actually reaches $0$, however, in the real world, no quantity is truly continuous.  It's made up of a large but finite number of discrete chunks (atoms/molecules/cents/what-have-you).  Thus the continuous model necessarily approximate.  Because such models are typically based on the behavior of random processes, when the actual number of chunks becomes small, the approximation is typically no longer a very good one, so the continuous model can't tell you precisely when you'll actually run out of "stuff".

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this differential equation is an exponential function that decreases to zero. As $t$ tends to infinity, the mass *approaches* zero, but it is never at zero.